# What type of object is returned by EF stored procedure call?

Tags: entity-framework, stored-procedures, ef-database-first

I am using Entity Framework (v6.1) with the Database First method. I have created my EDMX file and it references a stored procedure I selected while creating the EDMX via the EF wizard. My question is how do I use what the stored procedure returns?

Below is my dbContext and the name of the stored procedure `GetHtmlContent`. The stored procedure takes `contentId` as an integer parameter.

Here is the SQL of the stored procedure `GetHtmlContent` ..

```
SELECT 
   HtmlContent.contentId,
   HtmlContent.[Name] AS 'Name',
   HtmlContent.HTML AS 'HTML',
   HtmlContentCategory.CategoryTitle
FROM HtmlContent 
   LEFT JOIN HtmlContentCategory ON HtmlContent.CategoryID = HtmlContentCategory.HtmlContentCategoryID
WHERE HtmlContent.ContentId= @ContentId
```

Below is what I get when I hover over the stored procedure method contained within the dataContext to see what is returned.

`System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectResults<GetHtmlContent_Result> dbContext.GetHtmlContent(contentId)`

This is where I am getting confused ...

1. Is the `<GetHtmlContent_Result>` a type representing the dataset returned by the stored procedure?
2. What is `System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectResults`?
3. Since I am accepting a collection of records from the stored procedure do I need to create a class to hold the results of the stored procedure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Is the  a type representing the dataset returned by the stored procedure?**

`GetHtmlContent_Result` is representing each record that is produced by stored procedure.

```
HtmlContent.contentId,
HtmlContent.[Name] AS 'Name',
HtmlContent.HTML AS 'HTML',
HtmlContentCategory.CategoryTitle
```

**What is System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectResults?**

> The ObjectResult is an enumerable collection class, but it is a
>   forward-only collection so once it has been enumerated, you cannot
>   enumerate it again. For example, if you call ToList on the result,
>   e.g., GetDetailsForOrder(3).ToList(), then you cannot subsequently
>   provoke another enumeration by calling ToList again, binding the
>   results to a control or executing a foreach over the results. - [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg699321.aspx)

**Since I am accepting a collection of records from the stored procedure do I need to create a class to hold the results of the stored procedure?**

It's just like other entities that represent tables in the database, a POCO. You can use it directly.